# Want to output a visual price

Tags: javascript

ok, I've spent the past 5 hours trying to codge together a small javascript code for a website.

Basically the widths are set values of 2 or 4 (which the user will use a simple drop-down option).

Length can be anything from 1 to 60.

The price will be a fixed price, so can just be hidden out of the way.

Now this is where I start to go South with the situation, I'm having problems spitting the result out into a div area on the page, this is what I have so far;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function only_numbers(value){
  var check_this = value;
  var expression = /^\d*\.*\d*$/;
  if(expression.test(check_this)){ return true; }
  else{ return false; }
}
function calculate(){
 var lengthVal = document.mult.lengthVal.value;
 var heightVal = document.mult.heightVal.value;
 var priceVal = document.mult.priceVal.value
 var showValue = 0;

 if(only_numbers(lengthVal) && only_numbers(heightVal) && only_numbers(priceVal)){
   var showValue = ((lengthVal * heightVal) * 1.25) * priceVal;
   //      showValue = Math.round(showValue * 100) / 100;
   document.getElementById('showValue').innerHTML = "showValue";
 }else{
   alert("Please enter only numerical values.");
 }

}
  </script>

 </head>

 <body>
 <form name="mult">
 Length: <input type="text" name="lengthVal" /> <br />
 Height: <input type="text" name="heightVal" /> <br />
 Price: <input type="text" name="priceVal" /> <br />
 <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()" />
</form>

<div id="showValue"></div>
```

I know I've not sorted the price out to be hidden and is just an open variable atm, please guys, any help would be great.

Comment: so what is the actual problem? what's the error message? can you show the jsfiddle demonstrating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('showValue').innerHTML = "showValue";
```

You probably want to write your variable value in there, not the string "showValue". So you should be using:

```
document.getElementById('showValue').innerHTML = showValue;
```

Comment: you have no idea how thick I feel right now, either way I appreciate it, thank you, just a quick question, how would I set the price as a fixed thing? so I don't need the input, having problems there too.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the whole form? Then I believe you don't need js at all, just add a div with the value in your HTML. Or do I misunderstand you?